# Relational Objects and Triggers Going Slow?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a sql object in my table that has values that depend on the table's status. When I update the table I want to proc a trigger that then updates the appropriate object to show the changes.

So I have code that looks something like

```
:new.obj.valueName := :new.valueName;
```

But this goes pretty darn slow, this line makes it take around 50-60 times as long to update the table's objects. I tried with the following statement

```
:new.value2 := :new.value1
```

And this takes much less time. Is there something I'm missing about updating objects like this?